# fontawsome after deploy in Angular 6

Tags: angular

After `ng build --aot --build -c=production` the font awseome fonts files appeared in my dist

[image]

I tried to edit the path in the font-awsome.css but it doesn't work.

Comment: i think best practice is add them into assets folder. edit then before build

Comment: I tried but same problem if you put in css url(../fonts/font-awesome.css)

Comment: have you use like this `@font-face
  font-family: MyriadPro-BoldCondIt_0
  src: url(/assets/fonts/MyriadPro-BoldCondIt_0.otf)
` my font file is inside of `assets/fonts` and its works